# Slow down JQuery sort

Tags: jquery

I'm sorting div's via tinysort plugin. Can I slow down animation, I'm thinking with .fadein() but don't know how to implement? Here's my sort code.

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#results < div").tsort("",{attr:"id"});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at [their examples page](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/#animatedsorting), you'll see the section on animated sorting using this piece of code:

```
$Li.tsort().each(function(i,el){
    var $El = $(el);
    var iFr = $.data(el,'h');
    var iTo = i*iLnH;
    $El.css({position:'absolute',top:iFr}).animate({top:iTo},500);
});
```

That `500` is a millisecond value representing the animation's duration, which you could increase to slow down your animation. [More info on `.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Yup, looking at plugin documentation usually helps :)